# Angular js убрать пустой option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<select id="select_tour_type"
        class="form-control"
        name="tourType"
        ng-controller="TypeTours"
        ng-init="getTypeTours()"
        ng-model="formData.tours_type_id">
    <option value="0">Выбрать город</option>
    <option
            ng-repeat="type in types"
            value="{{type.id}}"
            ng-bind="type.name">
    </option>
</select>
```

В базе 2 типа, но option вылетает 3 штуки, причем первый  - пустой.
Как убрать пустой option и почему так происходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вот этот? `<option value="0">Выбрать город</option>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для селекта лучше использовать [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Пустой элемент добавляется, так как используется `ng-model` и значение модели не установлено, а выбранный элемент нужно привести в соответствие модели.

Убрать его можно либо присвоив значение модели либо добавив option с соответствующим значением и `ng-if="false"`

Например:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('TypeTours', function($scope) {
    $scope.types = [{
      id: 0,
      name: 'Выбрать город'
    }, {
      id: 1,
      name: 'name1'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'name2'
    }];
    $scope.formData = {
      tours_type_id: 0
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TypeTours">
  <select id="select_tour_type" class="form-control" name="tourType" ng-init="getTypeTours()" ng-model="formData.tours_type_id" ng-options="type.id as type.name for type in types">
  </select>
  {{formData.tours_type_id}}
</div>
```

Comment: type.id as type.name for type in types

Comment: Можете объяснить что это строчка делает

Comment: @ruslik, в ответе присутствует ссылка на справку - там все возможные варианты представлены, в данном случае: перебираются все type из types, и name показывают как текст optinon, а id - как значение

Comment: получается в моем пример достаточно указать при инициализации модель а option можно  сделать и моим методом

Comment: @ruslik, да можно